# IMAP Email webclient in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, imap

I am trying to create a simple web email client in C#/ASP.NET. I am trying to use Aspose.Email DLL to connect the to the email server via IMAP and show the emails to the user. Now I am thinking of storing the fetched emails on the filesystem/database or simply fetching and showing these emails on each request.

I think storing email body for all users might increase my database size, but then users would want to page through the results. What is the best strategy to handle emails once fetched via IMAP?

Answer (score 2):

Some regular desktop email clients download emails in advance and store them locally so that they can be displayed more quickly to the user (and for other practical reasons pertaining to search and even navigation, as you mentioned).

Others download the headers only (enough to display a list of emails in a folder) and then download the full body only upon request (when the user opens an email in the list). In the end it's just a tradeoff, and you have to see what works best in your scenario.

Personally I think downloading all emails in a folder at the start is overkill and I've seen clients get stuck for hours downloading emails for particularly large folders. A good option would be to display just enough to show a windowful of information, and get the rest as the user scrolls down - but that's not trivial to implement. Anyhow, the [IMAP4 Implementation Recommendations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2683) teach you a few tricks to optimise communications with the server and avoid many common pitfalls present in the more popular desktop clients.

If you're worrying about your database growing, you could store only metainformation in the database, and keep the emails themselves on the filesystem (e.g. save them to .eml files). Again, the best solution may vary depending on your particular context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/). It is an open-source .NET mail library.

Comment: MailSystem.NET is a tool to connect with POp/IMPA enabled servers and access emails. I already have that functionality. My question is what to do with the fetched emails? Store just headers, or entire body in local database?
What are the best practices for IMAP web clients?

Comment: I would ask the user, if it want to keep the emails on the server or download them entirely for space reasons. If you don't want such a functionality, you can store the entire email local, but don't delete the emails on the server.